# Moodle 2.9x theme sticky footer Safari issue

Tags: html, css, safari, moodle, sticky-footer

I've successfully tested a sticky footer implementation in my Moodle 2.9x custom theme which works in Chrome 46, Win/Linux FireFox 31-39, IE 8/9/10/11 & Edge, Android 4.2+, Opera 33+, etc. Unfortunately Safari is creating block space at the bottom of all layouts. Example:
[Safari moodle theme sticky footer problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHSE2.jpg)

I've discovered if you comment out this line:

```
<?php echo $OUTPUT->standard_end_of_body_html(); ?>
```

the footer then sticks in Safari for all apple devices (mobile/desktop) and all other browsers. This line add the Javascript/Jquery code for the user_menu() which I am needing.  Can someone help in discovering what is being injected into the page which is causing footer to bounce up and not stick to the page bottom?

**columns1.php** layout code:

```
<?php $html = theme_ksumoodle_get_html_for_settings($OUTPUT, $PAGE);
echo $OUTPUT->doctype() ?>
<html <?php echo $OUTPUT->htmlattributes(); ?>>
<head>
<title><?php echo $OUTPUT->page_title(); ?></title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo $OUTPUT->favicon(); ?>" />
<?php echo $OUTPUT->standard_head_html() ?>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body <?php echo $OUTPUT->body_attributes(); ?>>
<?php echo $OUTPUT->standard_top_of_body_html() ?>

<?php require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/includes/header.php');  ?>
<div id="page" class="container-fluid">
 <div id="page-content" class="row-fluid">
<section id="region-main" class="span12">
<?php 
   echo $OUTPUT->main_content();
?>
</section>
 </div>
</div>

<?php require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/includes/footer.php'); ?>
<?php echo $OUTPUT->standard_end_of_body_html(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**footer.php code:**
   `<footer>
        <?php echo $OUTPUT->login_info(); ?>
        <div class="ksuseparator"><!-- gold bar separator --></div>
        <div class="ksucopyright">University Copyright</div>
 </footer>`

**CSS code:** 
    `html, body {
     font-family:'Nunito',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
     font-weight:300;
     padding:0;
     margin:0;
     border:0;
     height:100%;
    }
    body {
     background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
     display:table;
     width:100%;
     overflow-y:scroll; 
    }
    footer {
     color:#fff;
     display:table-row;
     height:1px;
     background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #000;
    }`

Only showing code relevant to sticky footer implementation. Reference https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Upc_fwaiosg.  Please don't referenece ryanfait or other sticky footer sites. I've searched the web quite a bit before posting here and no solutions worked since Moodle inserts script tags at footer and this is where the issue stems from. Ryan fait and others are basic web page solutions without PHP scripting, so they don't work.

Comment: Have you looked at the code of the generated page? You should be able to see exactly what code is being inserted if you look at this page in your browser, then right click > view page source

Comment: Yes, I have. I used firebug, viewed source, Safari dev tools, etc. The problem is that the line <?php echo $OUTPUT->standard_end_of_body_html(); ?> inserts .js code, a jumbled list of functions; nothing readily apparent affecting the spacing, margins, padding, etc, so, I don't know how/why it's affecting Safari.

Comment: If I disable JavaScript in Safari Web Inspector, the footer sticks to the bottom fine. Here is the full page code: http://www32.zippyshare.com/v/gMvLoDdU/file.html. Right after the <footer> tags is where the problem resides, in the js scripts. Ideas? Help?

Comment: I've found that if I put a breakpoint at "YUI.add('moodle-core-lockscroll')", then the footer sticks in Safari.  Here is a screenshot with code: http://s28.postimg.org/82gkf3ddp/Moodle_Footer_YUI_function.jpg.  Any ideas?